# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable in map function, using numpy array

Tags: python, list, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

My goal is to normalize each line of a 2D numpy array / matrix. I thought it would be very simple..
I am trying to do a map operation like the following code. I looked for this error, which happens when calling an array like a function, which is not my case..

The input parameter (p_list) is a 2D numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

def normalize(p_list):
  if (type(p_list) == list):
    L = p_list
  else:
    L = p_list.tolist()    # Converts numpy matrix to list of lists.
  print(type(L))           # L is of type list ! (even if p_list is of type numpy.ndarray)
  return list(map(lambda p: np.linalg.norm(p), L))
```

My error, which occurs at the list(map(...)) line. :

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Sorry for my misunderstanding, if this problem has already been solved.. :/

Comment: I do not get any errors when I run the code.

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve]. When I input `np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)` I don't get that error. Please do not post code that does not reproduce your error

Comment: As an aside, this function is really unnecessary. Why use numpy at all if you are going to convert to a list then use `map`... only to use `numpy` function! The entire thing could be replaced with simply `np.linalg.norm(arr, axis=1)`